# Basics of PyQt5 and PyOpenGL

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyopengl

I'm trying to learn how to use PyQt5 and PyOpenGL to do a simple gui for display some shapes. I searched a lot but i didnt find any example/tutorial that show me the basics. I just want to draw simple shapes in the widget of this [mainwindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02I1O.png). Here is the code from the ui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.openGLWidget = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 591, 451))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Does this code do what you want it to? What happens when you run it and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry about that. The code that i posted just generates the mainwindow that shows in the picture. I want to draw things in the black widget that you can see in the picture using PyOpenGL, but i dont know how to make it @skrrgwasme

Answer (score 0):

Based on code from [Trying to get PyQt5 and OpenGL working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762549/trying-to-get-pyqt5-and-opengl-working). I found it using Google.

You assign own method to `self.openGLWidget.paintGL` and draw OpenGL inside this method.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.uic import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.openGLWidget = QtWidgets.QOpenGLWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 50, 591, 451))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.openGLWidget.initializeGL()
        self.openGLWidget.resizeGL(651,551)
        self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL

        timer = QTimer(self.centralwidget)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.openGLWidget.update) 
        timer.start(1000)

    def paintGL(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0);
        glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,0);
        glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0);
        glEnd()

        gluPerspective(45, 651/551, 0.1, 50.0)
        glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```